# Calling ES 3rd party script method from F# Fable

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I'm trying to get Fable to compile the following code correctly but am unable to do so:

```
module AppView
#r "../../../node_modules/fable-core/Fable.Core.dll"
open Fable.Core
open Fable.Import.Browser
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
[<Import("default", from="../../../js/3rd/riot.js")>]
module riot_js =
  let mount:((string*obj)->array<obj>) = jsNative

type App
  (
    tagName:string
    ,state
    ,store
  ) = 
  member public x.AppTag =
    (riot_js?mount ("app", state))
    // does not compile: The value or constructor 'riot_js' is not defined.
    // (riot_js.mount ("app", state))
    // compiles wrongly to: riot_js.mount(["app", this.state]);
```

Trying `riot_js?mount` would magically cause riot_js to not exist any more and trying `riot_js.mount` compiles into `riot_js.mount(["app", this.state]);`.

Mount does not take one argument but 2 but it either won't transpile or transpile wrong.

For now I have one of the strangest looking solutions:

```
[<Emit("riot_js")>]
let riot_js (x: int): obj = jsNative
...
((riot_js 1)?mount ("app", state))
```

This returns an array but again Fable does not let me take the first element in a "normal" way:

```
((riot_js 1)?mount ("app", state))?[0]
```

Gives me red on `[` with error `Unexpected symbol '[' in expression. Expected identifier, '(' or other token.`

And

```
((riot_js 1)?mount ("app", state)).[0]
```

Gives red on everything with error `The field, constructor or member 'Item' is not defined.`

The following "works"

```
((riot_js 1)?mount ("app", state))?``0``
```

And is compiled to:

```
riot_js.mount("app", this.state)["0"];
```

Not the best result someone can get. I'll let this question sit for a while and set a bounty on it for a week or so before opening 2 issues with Fable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to compile to the right ES and does not need the `?` so it'll be strongly typed.

```
open Fable.Core.JsInterop
type Riotjs = 
  {
    mount:(System.Func<string,obj,string []>)
  }
let riot = (importAll<obj> "../js/3rd/riot.js") :?> Riotjs
let app = riot.mount.Invoke("app",(createObj []))
```

I set initial state to type `obj` but can use a strong typed application state as well.

ES generated is:

```
export var app = riot.mount("app", {});
```